# Running JS on web page from .Net Core

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, html

I have a URL which I need to modify its HTML. I wrote a JS snippet which modifies it the way I need. I then need to download the source of this newly modified HTML.

I'm on .NET Core so I can't use the `WebBrowser` control. Is there any way to execute JavaScript on a website from C# and then download the result?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to run a JavaScript snippet on a web page. From there, I need to download the modified source. If I was using .NET Framework, I could use the `WebBrowser` control in Winforms, but as .NET Core does not support Winforms, I'm unsure how to 1)execute the JS on the page. 2) download the modified HTML. Hopefully this clears things up.

Comment: Just to confirm: you're working on a .net core web project(MVC Core or Razor Pages), correct?

Comment: It is .NET Core, but not a web project.

Comment: So you have a desktop app, and you're making a request to a site(GET?, POST?), and you want to inject some JS that alters the HTML that comes back, and then you want to download said HTML? Again, you might want to flesh out your question as much as possible because there aren't nearly enough details to make it clear what you're trying to do. A code sample of what you have so far would be helpful too.

Comment: That's correct. I'm not sure what else to include as I thought it was fairly straight forward. I don't have any code for this at the moment since I'm unsure how to inject the JS to begin with. I'm not exactly looking for code, just a point in the right direction to accomplish this task.